# Using URL to fill in Form %20 issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using website URL to pre-fill a html form.

however if my url is test.test.uk/test?notes=hello world

the broswer turns it into test.test.uk/test?notes=hello%20world as it should !

in return entering "hello%20world" into my form

is there anyway in javascript or html i could change this issue.

Please take into account i am super rookie.

how would i use this function below correctly?

Current Method tried to use to remove %20 from URL. Embedded in footer of every page in < script > tags.

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=       ([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
if (results==null){
   return null;
}
else{
   return results[1] || 0;
}
```

}

Comment: [decodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)

Comment: `... else return decodeURI(results[1]);`?

Comment: @SurajOdedra There are two things here. First, your second question is too broad, hence why you get a too broad answer. If you'd spend an hour doing beginner's tutorials, you'd understand why your question cannot be answered in a single line. Second, SO is not a free help-service, but a community driven resource database that must also cater to the future -- which means you need to show _effort_ to receive help, that's how it works. A request for copy-paste code without any effort on your end will yield negative feedback. This is not personal, but the standard here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `decodeUriComponent` to remove URI encoding from your text.

Here is a link to some documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Comment: would this work for my URL which will never be static? if so what code would i embedd for example on the html form or footer of my website so it alters the URL. i dont mind page refreshes im really struggling with this one.

Comment: @SurajOdedra You really need to look into a beginner's Javascript tutorial/guide and figure this out yourself. It does not make a difference whether the argument you pass to the function is -- in this case -- a string literal, or a reference to an already existing string object. This is a fundamental construct that is very early on in the learning curve.